# Calling endEditing in custom container view controller hides keyboard but doesn't change keyboard responder

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, uiresponder

In my custom container view controller I need to hide the keyboard when some things occur.

Because I don't know who the first responder is I just force close it as follows:

```
for (UIViewController *child in self.childViewControllers) {
        [child.view endEditing:YES];
}
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

The keyboard hides - which is great - but when I tap on a different text field - the previous text field which was the first responder before calling `endEditing` still gets the keyboards input.

Am I missing something here? Shouldn't it have resigned its first responder status? shouldn't the text field that was tapped get to be the first responder?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `resignFirstResponder`  for that view .